# Automation issue on tabbar in iphone

Tags: javascript, ios6, instruments, iphone-5, ios-ui-automation

I am using the automation on instruments tools check my application using the java script when i app have two tabbars when i click the second tab via javascript  following code

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var tabbar = window.tabBar().buttons()["Product"].tap();
UIALogger.logStart("Logging element tree …");
UIALogger.logPass();
```

its worked perfectly. In the product tab have one UITableviewcontroller now i am write the javascript for click the tableview cell like as`

```
tabar.tableviews()[0].cells()[0].tab;
```

is not worked. how can i handle this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to start at the tab bar to find your table view, but I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. I'm working on some UIAutomation scripts as well, so here are a couple of snippets -- hopefully one of them is relevant.

To tap a button in a UIToolBarController I use this:

```
var app = target.frontMostApp();
app.mainWindow().tabBar().buttons()["Saved"].tap(); // The name of the button is "Saved".
```

You can use the index as well, like [0] for the first tab bar button. On a screen with a UITableView I use this to tap a cell in it:

```
app.mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()["Name"].tap(); // The cell is named "Name".
```

Again, you can use an index as well. Note that I don't start at the tab bar but instead start with the app variable.

If something's not working the way you think it should, always log out the tree and take a look at what it contains. That's always helped me:

```
app.mainWindow().tableViews()[0].logElementTree();
```

The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) on this has more examples.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I already got the answer.Any way i will give your answer is correct